# How to iterate over columns with Sapply for Pearson coefficient

Tags: r, loops, sapply

[i] indicates where I have to iterate pearsons coefficient over the columns and how to convert this into a dataframe attached onto a variable?

Code example:

```
*INSTEAD OF DOING THIS*
F.ReedBunting.pear<- cor.test(W_farmland_mean$Years,W_farmland_mean$ReedBunting,method='pearson')
F.Whitethroat.pear<- cor.test(W_farmland_mean$Years,W_farmland_mean$Whitethroat,method='pearson')
F.Rook.pear<- cor.test(W_farmland_mean$Years,W_farmland_mean$Rook,method='pearson')
.
.
.
*HOW CAN IT BE DONE QUICKLY WITH THIS*
workspaceone <- sapply(W_farmland_mean, function(x){
    cor.test(W_farmland_mean$Years, W_farmland_mean[, 1[i]], method = 'pearson')
})
```

Comment: W_farmland_mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try:

```r
result_cor <- apply(W_farmland_mean,2,function(x){cor.test(W_farmland_mean$Years,x, method = 'pearson')$estimate})
```

It will extract the Pearson coefficient of the comparison of each columns with the column `years` of your dataset.

**Example**
With the `mtcars` dataset:

```r
df <- mtcars[c(1:10),]
```

```r
> df
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

And if we apply the function:

```r
result_cor = apply(df,2, function(x){cor.test(x,df$mpg,method ='pearson')$estimate})
```

And you get the following output:

```r
> result_cor
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 1.0000000 -0.8614165 -0.7739868 -0.8937223  0.5413585 -0.5991894  0.5494131 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
 0.4796102  0.2919683  0.6646449 -0.3711956
```

Comment: How could you extract both the estimate and p.value?